# Firefox firing change event on input.attr("type", "number")

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm experiencing a problem, only in firefox, when an input is focused, and I change the input type from `"text"` to `"number"`, a change event is triggered and the input loses focus.

What I want to achieve is to change the input to a number field on focus, allow edit, and change the input toLocaleString() on blur.

Here are my codes:

```js
$("input").focusin(function() {
  $(this).val(toNumber($(this).val()));
  $(this).attr("type", "number");
});

$("input").focusout(function() {
  $(this).attr("type", "text");
  $(this).val("$ " + toCost($(this).val()));
});

// Added during edit to make code testable
$('input').on('change', function(){ console.log('changed'); })

function parseNumber(value) {
  var result = parseFloat(toNumber(value));
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    return result;
  }
  return 0;
}

function toNumber(str) {
  return str.replace(/\s/g, "").replace(/\$/g, "").replace(/,/g, "");
}

function toCost(number) {
  return parseNumber(number).toLocaleString();
}
```

```html
<!-- Added during edit to make code testable -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```

I can't figure out why in Firefox the input is triggering a change event and losing focus when I select it. It works the way I want it to when I try to use `$("#myInput").focusin()` on the console though.

It works fine on Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this!

Comment: Not a trivial change due to the way the the shadow dom handles number input. Not surprised it loses focus. Try to `focus()` on it after the change

Comment: Do you really want that `$` is part of the form value? Why do you want to solve it this way instead of using an element before the input element that holds the `$` and then style those two elemens in a way that they look like one input element?

Comment: if I call `focus()` it will recur infinitely.

Comment: it's more of the `,` from toLocaleString() that I want, for readability, so whether to have the `$` there or not doesn't change the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently using this as a solution:

```js
function is_firefox() {
    return navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0;
}

$("input").focusin(onFocusIn);

$("input").focusout(onFocusOut);

$('input').change(onInputChange);

function onFocusIn() {
  $(this).val(toNumber($(this).val()));
  $(this).attr("type", "number");

  // remove on 'change' and 'focusout', and add back after a short delay
  if (is_firefox()) {
    $(this).off("change");
    $(this).off("focusout");
    setTimeout(function(element){
      element.change(onInputChange);
      element.focusout(onFocusOut);
    }, 15, $(this));
  }
}

function onFocusOut() {
  $(this).attr("type", "text");
  $(this).val("$ " + toCost($(this).val()));
}

function onInputChange() {
  console.log("changed");
}

$("input").focusout();
    
function parseNumber(value) {
  var result = parseFloat(toNumber(value));
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    return result;
  }
  return 0;
}

function toNumber(str) {
  return str.replace(/\s/g, "").replace(/\$/g, "").replace(/,/g, "");
}

function toCost(number) {
  return parseNumber(number).toLocaleString();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1000"/>
```

I don't think it's the perfect solution, but it works for me now.